# Why is bundler insisting on an exact gem version number when the gemspec states an open constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, travis-ci

I'm contributing to the Ruby gem [koudoku](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku) and trying to get Travis CI to work.

The gem was set up with Travis a few days ago but all builds are failing with this error  message ([example](https://travis-ci.org/andrewculver/koudoku/jobs/42271473)):

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec-rails (~> 2.14.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0) ruby depends on
        rack (~> 1.2.1) ruby
    capybara (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rack (1.0.0)
```

The offending lines in the `gemspec` are:

```
s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.0"
s.add_development_dependency 'capybara'
```

I forked the gem and changed the second line so it requires capybara version `>= 2.4.0`, but when I run my own build on Travis I get the [exact same error](https://travis-ci.org/georgemillo/koudoku/jobs/42743296).

What's confusing me the most is, when you look in [Capybara's own gemspec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/capybara.gemspec) you can see **it doesn't state it depends on rack version 1.0.0 exactly**. The [real dependency](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2.4.0/capybara.gemspec#L27) is on rack version `>= 1.0.0`.

Why is bundler insisting on 1.0.0 exactly when Capybara itself doesn't require this? How can I get Travis to run the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that is not Travis-specific problem.

```
⌚ 17:10:45 ▷ /tmp/koudoku ▷ ⭠ master ▷ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Resolving dependencies........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec-rails (~> 2.14.0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0) ruby depends on
        rack (~> 1.2.1) ruby

    capybara (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rack (1.0.0)
```

This is what happened to me when I `git clone`’d koudoku and run `bundle` on the freshly downloaded sources. This occurred on `ruby 2.1.5`, but Travis had the same problem on 1.9.3.

It looks like you have somehow tuned your gems to make them work, while the from-the-scratch process is broken. I have no clue why `rack >= 1.0.0` is not working for `1.2.1`, but I would suggest you to clear your system (create new gemset using `rvm` or like) and try to make things working locally.

Sorry for posting this as an answer, but it’s too long to fit the “comment” field.

Hope it helps.

Versions:

```
▷ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.2 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis 
▷ gem --version
2.4.4
▷ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.7.6
```

**UPD** For unknown reason adding this line to `gemspec` leads to infinite `Resolving dependencies` dots printing:

```
  s.add_development_dependency "rack", "~> 1.2.1"
```

Comment: Okay, I just `cd`ed to the gem's directory and ran `rvm gemset create koudoku`, `rvm use 2.1.4@koudoku`, and `bundle install` ... but it installed everything fine locally. (It installed rack v1.5.2 for what it's worth.) Am I "clearing my system" correctly or did I miss a step?

Comment: Sounds like you did everything correctly. I updated my answer with versions.

Comment: I just updated everything and did the above again with ruby 2.1.5, rvm 1.26.3, gem 2.4.4 and bundler 1.7.7.... and it still works fine. Dafuq?

Comment: Wait. Adding `s.add_dependency "rack", "~> 1.2.1"` to `gemspec` on my box turned `bundle install` not to break (don’t ask.) It’s currently printing dots for another 5 mins :)

Comment: Could this be an issue with bundler?

Comment: It **is** an issue with bundler. Are you on Mac/Win? Because me and Travis are both on Linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66049/discussion-between-mudasobwa-and-georgemillo).